# In Google Drawings, how do I put a ^ or a ~ over a letter?

Tags: google-drawings

Can I do this in Google Drawings without having to mess around with importing images?

I don't suppose there's a way of getting **LaTeX** in Google drawings?

[image: example]

Comment: This question was incorrectly edited. I wanted to know if there's a way of getting LaTeX or TeX (or equations) in google drawings.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to insert text in Google Drawings.

Insert a text box
Add text within shapes
Add Word Art

From [example](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1W5zelZZp93S2FQ8KU3Gk9zNjW5ct7G6Dx3sYw0ffRJI/edit?usp=sharing)
[image: example ỹ]

**References**
[How to use text in drawings - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179185?hl=en&ref_topic=1361613)